# MSSQL Skip Group by on Sum column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I can't find relevant title and description on what i am trying to do. So i hope you could understand from the example.

- I have these columns two of which are quantities.
- Of which one (LotQty) is a sum.
- The other (SumQuantity) must be sum of the former.
- The rest (Productid and Lot) stay grouped by.

The result should look like this:

```
    SumQuantity    Productid  LotQty        Lot
    512            40652      256.000000    2020-12-20
    512            40652      256.000000    2020-12-21
```

I.e. SumQuantity=sum(LotQty). 
How should i change my select (below) to create that effect?

```
    select s.productid,sum(s.cuquantity) LotQty,la.Value Lot 
    from log l 
    left join logstock s on s.logid=l.id
    left join Logstockattributes la on la.LogStockID=s.id and la.AttributeID=10
    where l.receiptid=5950195
    group by productid,la.value
```

the result is:

```
     Productid    LotQty        Lot
     40652        256.000000    2020-12-20
     40652        256.000000    2020-12-21
```

Sample table

```
  Logid        Productid      Cuquantity    Lot
      1        40652          256.000000    2020-12-20
      2        40652          255.000000    2020-12-21
      3        40652            1.000000    2020-12-21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a window function:

```
select s.productid, sum(s.cuquantity) as LotQty, la.Value as Lot,
       sum(sum(s.cuquantity)) over () as totalLogQty
from log l left join
     logstock s
     on s.logid = l.id left join
     Logstockattributes la
     on la.LogStockID = s.id and la.AttributeID = 10
where l.receiptid = 5950195
group by productid,la.value
```

Comment: 10x. that was quick. and actually might work....i admit i didn't know how to sum in a sum. now i have to test it

EDIT: Test it and there is just one small thingy - it works ONLY when where clause looks like this:
"where l.receiptid = 5950195 AND productid=40652"
else the result is 2048 for totalLogQty column instead of 512 (i.e. 3 productids linked to the receiptid and a NULL row (from my left joins)).
So basically - It works just as i wished (no group by:) but it comes with a price...
Anyway - 10x again. I'll mark it as solution and i'll try to figure it out from here.